# git - Squashing pushed commits in the protected main branch

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-rebase

I have a bunch of similar commits that are polluting my commit history on the main branch.

Apparently, someone forgot the "Squash & Merge" while merging there branch.

Is there any way I can squash these commits now into a single commit ?

Note: **The main branch is protected, so I cannot write to it without a PR.**

**I have tried creating a separate branch and squashing the commits and raising a PR. But this does nothing.**

**It only adds on a commit to this very long list of commits.**

Is there any way to change these pushed commits ?

Comment: remove branch protection or give yourself rights to push directly (not sure how to do the latter but it's possible), then squash on main branch. For the future consider turning squash and merge as the default option.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel No way I can remove write protection. Also no rights to push directly, that would make write protection useless.

Any way I can do this without elevated access?

Comment: No you can't. Also, you didn't read my comment carefully. You can give elevated access just to _some_ users, meaning you can give it temporarily to yourself, then remove it.

Comment: Just in case, _"someone forgot"_ implies that it's more than one person working against that repo.... in such situations, rewriting branch history is _not_ the best thing to do. It can be done, I am not saying otherwise, but if the team is not used to git and doesn't understand the nuances of these operations, it can be **painful** to not mess it up by people already working on top of what is in the branch already.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I don't have access to do that. Thanks for clarifying that it's impossible. I was still searching for ways to do it via a PR.

Comment: @eftshift0 If I were to do that would this be sufficient: 1) Get the required access 2) Interactively rebase and squash the offending commits 3) Do a force push to `main` ?

If I had access would these steps work ?

Comment: that would work to get history of the branch the way you want.... _yes_. But does that magically modify the branches of other people who might already be working on the branch as it is right now? _no_. that will require some _additional_ work to clean up... and it is the _painful_ part of doing this (it's actually not _that_ difficult... it just requires _more work_ and getting everybody on the same page and getting rid of this branch and start using the new one.... that means running a _peculiar_ rebase for each one of the branches they are working on using the current _bad_ branch).

Comment: @eftshift0 Could you tell me how that peculiar rebase works ? Like what would be the command ? I thought if everyone did a `git fetch` on their side after the history has been adjusted then it should be fine. Am I wrong ? 

Asking this for future reference, this a pretty common problem it seems.

Comment: re last comment: no, this is not how git works. You would need to do an interactive rebase `git rebase -i HEAD~N` where N is the number of commits you want to squash/rewrite. But to apply it to github you'd need to force push as eftshift0 said

Comment: @MikeSzyndel yes but how do I fix other feature branches which have the "bad main" in their histories ?

Let's say I make a branch from main, and I continue working on it. Now let's say someone squashes/drops previous commits on `main` and effectively changes the history of `main`.

How do I get that to reflect now in my branch ? 

Will a simple `git fetch` from `main` work ?

Comment: This is how I would run things. Trunk based development. Short lived feature branches. Deployments to prod are tags or a separate branch (so you always know what's out there, with tooling you can skip tag/branch and just keep the commit it). Squash branches on merge, so each branch is a single commit in main and is applied to the HEAD, not buried in history.

Comment: To answer your question. `git rebase main` will apply commits in a branch on top of main, one by one, then save that branch history (I'm not git expert, some things here probably have proper names). This way you'll end up with a branch where all commits not in main are on top of the branch, and history can be rewritten based on what happened in main.

Comment: You can try it with any two branches even locally. Something like `git checkout main` (starting point) `git checkout branch-a` 10x `git commit -m"messed up history" --allow-empty` then `git checkout branch-b` now you have 2 branches that are identical. `git checkout branch-a` `git rebase -i HEAD~10` and squash commits (instruction how to will show up). Now branch-a has 1 commit and branch-b has 10. `git checkout branch-b` `git commit -m"keep it in branch b" --allow-empty` `git rebase branch-a` and voila, branch-b keep the extra commit but now has same history as branch-a

Comment: @MikeSzyndel yes a simple rebase would work. Now I just have to get permission from my repo maintainer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. Not without the ability to modify the `main` branch directly.

Attempting to squash commits in a separate branch and then raising a PR to the main branch would not resolve the issue of the cluttered commit history. It will only add another commit on top of the existing ones.

The situation requires either elevated access or a change in repository management practices to effectively address the cluttered commit history.
And coordination with your repository maintainers and team members is essential for any action that involves rewriting the history of a shared branch like the `main` branch: If the history of the main branch were to be altered, all feature branches based on the old history would require rebasing.